# Take screenshot does not work with actual screen

Tags: automation, screen, screenshot, resolution, sikuli

I have screen resolution 1920x976 which clearly shown  from:

```
print Screen().getBounds()
```

Message:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=976]
```

Why when I use `img=capture(SCREEN)` and then save it to file my picture has 1369x858? Also the option "Take screenshot" in the IDE does not allow me to select more than 1396x858 because of that, all my patterns could not be found on the screen if they are beyond of that area.

Comment: hmm that's strange. I have just tried the same steps and in my case I managed to get the same resolution in the saved file as in the `Screen().getBounds()`. Maybe there is some issue in the way you save it to file? Can you add that to your question please?

Comment: Seems like problem is solved. I did not found the reason  but It happens when  run 2 virtual machines simultaneously . Just enough to turn one off and everything becomes ok